# MySQL is using wrong index, I think

Tags: mysql, indexing

This is my table:

```
- user_id INT (foreign key on `user` with the reference `id`)
- question_id INT (foreign key on `question` with the reference `id`)
- option_id INT (foreign key on `option` with the reference `id`)
- exam_id INT (foreign key on `exam` with the reference `id`)
- order INT
```

My Index is: `user_id, exam_id`

My Query:

```
select * from `user_answer` where `user_id` = '48' and `exam_id` = '1' and `order` > '10' order by `order` desc limit 1;
```

I think it should use my index but this is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'user_answer', 'range', 'user_answer_exam_id_foreign,user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', 'user_answer_exam_id_foreign', '4', NULL, '10', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Apperently, It is not using my index. When I use `FORCE INDEX`:

```
select * from `user_answer` force index (user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index) where `user_id` = '48' and `exam_id` = '1' and `order` > '10' order by `order` desc limit 1;

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'user_answer', 'ref', 'user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', 'user_answer_user_id_exam_id_index', '8', 'const,const', '10', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

Any idea what's wrong with me or MySQL ?

Comment: Try not putting quotes around your integer literals?  Also, can you explain a little bit about the data?  Is `order` a unique value in the table?  At present the combination of `order > 10 ORDER BY order DESC LIMIT 1` means that the optimiser believes that sorting by `order` first will be more beneficial than filtering by `user_id, exam_id`.

Comment: I am not sure how this affects the result, but just tried and `EXPLAIN` result is same.

Comment: also for your query its better to use combined index as `(user_id,exam_id,order)` and have the query follow where condition from left to right as you have now.

Comment: How many rows on the table, and how many have a user_id of 48 and how many an exam_id of 1?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I don't want to include `order` to the index because I have some other queries without `order` column so this index looks sufficient for me.

Comment: Other queries without order would still use the index with order as the last field.

Comment: @Kickstart 10 rows with `user_id = 48 and exam_id = 1`. Good to know that my other queries will use the index with `order`. Thanks.

Comment: How many other rows on the table? Are all rows for user_id 48?

Comment: @Kickstart Actually, it just contains 10 rows. Does the row count affects the indexes used?

Comment: @Kickstart I just added some rows with different `user_id`, and now it's using the correct index without `FORCE INDEX`. I didn't know that  row count affects the indexes used.

Comment: Yes, very much so. If the index does not narrow down the rows much then MySQL will ignore it. As a very rough rule of thumb if an index doesn't reduce the rows below about 1/3 then it is ignored (this is very rough, but gives you an idea).

Comment: @Kickstart Thank you very much! Can you add this as an answer then I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will ignore indexes which do not narrow the results down by much.

As a very rough rule of thumb if an index doesn't reduce the rows below about 1/3 then it is ignored (this is very rough, but gives you an idea). Ie, if you have 100 records and the index only narrows it down to ~40 then MySQL will likely ignore the index. It is faster for it to check each row individually than it is for it to use the index.

Annoyingly even when it choses not to use an otherwise valid index, it still reports the query on the slow query log for now using an index!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that row count in the table affects the indexes used.